# Any apache ignite deb/rpm mirror?

Tags: centos, ignite, rpm, deb

Both
https://dl.bintray.com/apache/ignite-rpm/ and https://dl.bintray.com/apache/ignite-deb/

Is "Forbidden!".

Where i can get "apache-ignite-2.8.1-1.noarch.rpm" for example... now? :(

Old link looks like : https://dl.bintray.com/apache/ignite-rpm/apache-ignite-2.8.1-1.noarch.rpm.

**Latest documentaion still points to Bintray (EOL).**

// https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/installation/deb-rpm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching for `apache-ignite-2.8.1-1.noarch.rpm` will find https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/packaging/rpm/apache-ignite.spec → apache-ignite.spec → "
ignite/packaging/rpm/"
https://github.com/apache/ignite/tree/master/packaging/rpm with files for rpm packaging.

Searching for `apache-ignite-2.8.1` will find https://ignite.apache.org/download.cgi#binaries **and** https://archive.apache.org/dist/ignite/2.8.1/ with the package `apache-ignite-2.8.1-bin.zip`

Move / copy the files to `rpmbuild/SOURCES/`:

```
SOURCES/
├── apache-ignite-2.8.1-bin.zip
├── apache-ignite.spec           # edit to    Version: 2.8.1
├── name.service
└── service.sh
```

Example, CentOS 8

```
$ rpmbuild -bb  apache-ignite.spec
.
 Wrote: /home/knudfl/rpmbuild/RPMS/noarch/apache-ignite-2.8.1-1.noarch.rpm
```

The package `apache-ignite-2.8.1-1.noarch.rpm` 394MB can be downloaded at https://drive.google.com/file/d/1U1_VeHA4-JX-Rp_813_1LnkreJtElfOk/view?usp=sharing